# Do parent file system snapshot reference it's children datasets data or only their onw data?

Tags: zfs, btrfs, snapshot

Data is referenced in as many snapshots you take and it will be deleted from disk only if you delete all snapshots that referenced said data as well as the data from the running volume, this holds true for both, btrfs and ZFS.

For example, in btrfs if I create `~/mifyle.txt` and then take an snapshot of `@home`, my file will not be deleted from disk unless I delete this snapshot and `~/myfile.txt`, the same happens with ZFS.

But what if I'm taking snapshots from `@` and `@home`? Will `~/myfile.txt` be referenced in *@* and *@home* snapshots or just in *@home* snapshots?

And does ZFS behave differently? If I create a file `rpool/home/myfile.txt`, where `rpool` is the parent and `rpool/home` is a child dataset, then take snapshots for `rpool` and `rpool/home`, will *myfile.txt* be referenced in both datasets snapshots or just in the children dataset snapshot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each dataset, whether child or parent, is its *own* file system. The file system is where files and directories are referenced and saved.

Snapshots done to **rpool** only affect the dataset **rpool**. Snapshots done to rpool/**home** only affect the dataset **home**.

Remember that **home** is *not* simply a directory within **rpool**, it is a file system that so happens to be *mounted* in the path /mnt/rpool/home.

If you save files within the **home** dataset, and then later destroy the **home** dataset, **all files and folders within the home dataset are gone: including those saved in its snapshots!** No such files were ever saved in the **rpool** dataset during the time **home** was mounted at /mnt/rpool/home.

This is true for snapshots as well. Taking snapshots for rpool/**home** does not create snapshots for **rpool**; only **home** snapshots are made.

The only reason you might be interested in **rpool** affecting rpool/**home** is when you use *recursive* actions on **rpool**, where any such *recursive* action will affect **rpool** *and all of its children,* including rpool/**home**.

If you make a *recursive* snapshot for **rpool**, it doesn't create a *single* snapshot. It creates *multiple* snapshots, one for *each* dataset.

This command will yield the following snapshots. -r is "recursive":

```
zfs snap -r rpool@important
```

1. rpool@important
2. rpool/home@important
3. rpool/media@important
4. rpool/isos@important
5. rpool/isos/stable@important
6. rpool/isos/testing@important

You can choose to destroy all of the snapshots with the following command. Notice the -r option:

```
zfs destroy -r rpool@important
```

If you prefer to be selective, you can destroy only specific snapshots without harming any of the others. Notice there is no -r option used:

```
zfs destroy rpool@important
zfs destroy rpool/media@important
```

Now you will be left with only the snapshots you have spared:

2. rpool/home@important
3. rpool/isos@important
4. rpool/isos/stable@important
5. rpool/isos/testing@important